# Looking for Online Exception Tracker for Java

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j, logback

Does anybody know something like [tracemycode.net](http://tracemycode.net) but for Java?

Looks like [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/en/software/jira/whats-new/jira-51) has something similar (see Capture Feedback), but it's not the same.

In ideal case with log4j/logback integration.

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't your server side code just print to a log on exception?

Using log4j for example? Doesn't seem necessary to need third party software to do this, and I don't know how tracemycode makes money

EDIT:

I think I understand now, you want a way to read exceptions created from a local app. Well this gets a bit risky, as any network communication can cause an exception, leading to infinite recursion, but as long as you exclude these exceptions from reporting you should be ok.

This would be easy to build. All you need to do is generate some helper class that you call in your exceptions to send the log to the server.

```
public class ExceptionReporter {

public static int sendReport(String aData)
    try {
        byte[] myData = aData.getBytes();
       /* Uploading the data */
       URL myURL = new URL(CONSTANTS.CentralURL);
       HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
       myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
       myConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
       myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
       OutputStream myOutputStream = myConnection.getOutputStream();
       myOutputStream.write(myData);
       myOutputStream.flush();
       myOutputStream.close();

       int status = ((HttpURLConnection) myConnection).getResponseCode();       
    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
         LocalLog.log(e.toString());     
    }


}
```

Then in all of you server code / app code you can use

```
try{
     // ...do stuff
}
catch (Exception e){
     ExceptionReporter.sendReport(e.getMessage());
}
```

Then your central server can take in these httpconnections, and save the sent in data to a database, or some other thread-safe solution.

Comment: Wanna know how often exception appears in which environments etc. Yes it will be nice embed it to own server side (servlet based) but that's not a my point. Let's imagine that we have N servers in K different locations etc. Exceptions appear on each server and logging locally. Having a single source of all errors will be a great plus for us.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TraceMyCode if you wanted as it clearly documents in the help section the end point and data structure required to send a crash log.

http://tracemycode.net/help